# Can I call multiple get_headers() at the same time in PHP?

Tags: php, multithreading

I have to check if many URLs have redirects. Right now, I'm using a loop and get_headers(). As you can imagine, this is extremely slow. Would it be possible to call get_headers() many times at the same time? (I believe this is called "threading"?)

If it isn't possible, what other options do I have?

Comment: You'd be better off just issuing multiple requests with cURL at the same time and then going over the results as they come in. This will be much easier than trying to do anything multithreaded.

Comment: PHP is not a multi-threaded language, and will never be one without fundamental internal redesigns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [process control functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) to fork a PHP process and do multiple things at the same time. Recent versions of the [cURL extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) also support sending multiple requests at the same time (check out the "multi" functions). cURL might be easier if you're not familiar with forking and monitoring processes.